# Mark form as unsubmitted in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, is there a way to mark a form that has already been submitted as unsubmitted (so it loses the `ng-submitted` class?

## Background:

In my css, I'm using the angular validation classes to accomplish the following:

- Initially, all inputs have a normal border color.
- If the user modifies an input to have an invalid value, set the border color to red.
- If the user clicks the submit button, set the border color of all invalid inputs to red.

I am accomplishing this like so:

```
input.ng-dirty.ng-invalid, .ng-submitted .ng-invalid {
    border-color: #F00;
}
```

That works fine. Now I have a form that submits an asynchronous request, and if the server responds with a success status, I want to clear the form (and effectively reset it to its original state). The problem is when I clear the form, it still has the `.ng-submitted` class, so all of the required fields have a red border. However I want them all to have a normal border.

I should be able to mark all of the fields as pristine using `$setPristine()`, but I don't see any way to mark the form as unsubmitted. Is this possible, or do I need to create and maintain my own class for doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can reset your form and thus mark it as `unsubmitted` using the following piece of snippet.

**Html:**

```
<input type="button" ng-click="reset(form)" value="Reset" />
```

**Angular Script:**

```
$scope.reset = function(form) {
    if (form) {
      form.$setPristine();
      form.$setUntouched();
    }
    $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
  };
```

This was taken from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: I think only `form.$setPristine();` is needed.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that `form.$setPristine()` would also set `$submitted` to `false`. I will still use `form.$setUntouched()` as well, since the form should technically be considered untouched, too. However I won't use the `$scope.user` stuff because that looks like that is specific to the example you are referencing.

Comment: No problem. I knew that `$scope.use` is irrelevant but i didn't want to harm the integrity of the snippet. I'm glad it helped you.